# Can't change cursor position in ckeditors widget

Tags: firefox, widget, ckeditor

Using firefox i can't change the cursor position in nested editables of a widget. for example at this demo http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets

Is there some workaround?

Thanks

Nils

Comment: I seem to have the same issue using Firefox on Windows. Firefox on Mac does not seem to have this bug. Looks like a FF issue. Any ckeditor staff comment on this?